# How to verify if @RequestHeader in null or not in spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring, request-headers

I want to check in the token is null or not
this is my method:

```
public Integer confirm(@RequestHeader(value="token") String token) {
         
         if(token==null) {
             return 1;
         }
         return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     }
```

it return the max value and not 1
Where is the problem here?

Comment: Check token is empty string or not,  it can't be null I think

Comment: so there is no way to check if token is null

Comment: We can use the defaultValue attribute to provide a default value for header. Example : `@RequestHeader(value = "token", defaultValue = "xy12vdv") String token)`

Comment: @AmitKumer Default value also worked for empty string right ?

Comment: Use required attribute and it will work: @RequestHeader(value="token", required = false)

Comment: defaultValue works good for me but required=false didn't work.